# How to Maintain d3 Color Scale with Link Severing and Re-joining

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors

I have a d3 block: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/70ad367d980d33160d0681881ab10aae

The functionality I am concerned with is the slider which severs links (based on this example: https://bl.ocks.org/jrladd/c76799aa63efd7176bd9006f403e854d). This functionality works, except the color scale I have implemented is not carrying over once the link threshold is changed. The color scale is correct the first time the graph renders, but it changes/is incorrect as soon as the threshold changes. When the threshold is returned to the lowest value, the color scale remains incorrect.

I tried using the same variable for the color scale for the initial rendering and new rendering, and this returned the same, incorrect result.

How do I maintain the accuracy of the color scale while severing and rejoining links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `console.log(d.value)` inside the event handler, you're gonna see that the value of the datum (`d.value`) in the enter selection (`linkEnter`) is **always** `179` (which is the last value). And that's expected, since the data-binding function by default binds the data by index.

That being said, the solution here is just using a [key function](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data):

```
link = link.data(newData, function(d){ return d.value});
//this is the key function -----^
```

Since the values in `d.value` are not unique, a better solution would be creating a **unique** property for the links.

Besides that, don't forget to update the colours in the "update" selection.

Here is the updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/59f0783654d89e5a45c55ecf150032bc

Comment: PS: You're gonna see that the colour function is returning black and white for the extreme values. You might want to adjust that function accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much - this answered my question perfectly and gave a great explanation. Could you please point me in the right direction for updating the color function to avoid super dark/light colors? Logically I would think the function would have to be told which colors to start and end the range with.